# Where do I find app profile page of Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Recently I have created a Facebook page, but I don't know how to update that page.

I logged in on [Facebook Developers Page](https://developers.facebook.com) and filled all the necessary information. But now hanging on to publish that page.

**Edit:** I just want to make a Facebook page, to create a Facebook page I login on facebook developers page and set the all the necessary settings that Facebook wants me to fill like : `Canvas URL` etc. and after filling all the necessary settings I got the `APP ID` and more. Now the problem is that I am not able to find-out how to view this app. I googled but not able to find the result :(

Now I want to check my page before apply on the particular Facebook page link.

Comment: Please clarify what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: @mark4o thanks for your reply, i edited my question now please make me correct, and help me. This is my first page that i have created that's why i don't have much experience of facebook. If anyone want more info then please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an application just to create a page. Just click [Create a Page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php) and fill in the information.

If you want the URL of your page you can copy it from the URL bar of your browser when you are on your page. (If it contains a `?` then omit everything from the `?` to the end.) If you want a custom username for your page, click Edit Page, then Basic Information, and find the "Username" section.  If your page has a username then the URL will be `https://www.facebook.com/username`.

If you want to add an existing app to your page, search for the app in the Facebook Search field at the top, click on it, and there will usually be a button or link there to install the app or add it to your page, if it is an app that is intended to be added to pages.

If you have developed your own Facebook app and want to add it to your page, see the instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/). Previously, all apps had an app profile page that could be used to add the app to your page, but that is no longer the case. Facebook now allows (and encourages) apps to provide a button or link for this purpose, which can be used in the app or shared on a page or on your own web site. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) for an example of how to do this. If you do not want to create a button on your app you can just go to the URL `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL` substituting `YOUR_APP_ID` and `YOUR_URL` with your App ID and your Canvas URL from your app settings. This will pop up a dialog where you can choose the page where you want to add the app.

Comment: Wow, lots of information and also exactly that i want. Thanks a lot.